# how to broadcast audio file to icecsat server using php

Tags: php, stream, audio-streaming, icecast

I have a `v-p-s` with `windows server 2003 (OS)` installed which i installed `ice cast stream service program` on it and i broadcast `m-p-3` files to this `ice cast` server using `v l c`.i want to broadcast to this server using `p-h-p` and html file upload i mean upload m-p-3 files using html form then broadcast it to the ice-cast server using `p-h-p`.

Tanks.

Comment: This is not a code writing service, and we are not here to design your system for you.

Comment: i just want to know is it possible to do as vlc player do with php or not and if it is possible then how @MarcB

Comment: just get a proper linux vps and run `Airtime` together with `Icecast`.

Comment: @TBR tnx but i have no linux is there any similar program for windows?

Comment: I am not aware of any readily usable solution. On windows a decent source client is Mixxx, but I'm not aware of any web functionality. You'd need to write all that from scratch, at which point a linux VPS is the much much cheaper option.

Comment: tnx for your help @TBR

Answer (score -1):

I broadcast via BuTT and Mixxx, If you want to live broadcast mp3 files then just load up mixxx add the mp3 from the Music folder on windows or wherever you keep them.

Now, you'll also need to add the ice cast server setting via the preferences option on mixxx e.g. live broadcast setting to connect mixxx to the ice cast server. On my website which is just a simple test one as i'm building a better one, I just use an image and use an hyperlink to the external ice cast stream e.g. http://externalIP:8000/stream and hey presto you can either live stream or auto dj stream, this is the easiest way to achieve this.

if you've managed to resolve this then good for you however hit me up if you like some help, no problem on mixxx and/or BuTT. peace and good luck

Comment: tnx for your answer this is exactly what i did already but as i mentioned in my question i'm looking for a way to broadcast from a web browser